# @OneToOne - Cascade all not saving the parent Id

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-cascade

guys ! I have problem with saving on the "child" table parent's id When persist the child object, the column with parent id is null..

**Parent ( User class)**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private long userId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "address")
private String address;

@Column(name = "postcode")
private int postCode;
```

**Child (Credential class)**

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name="credential")
public class Credentials {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;


@OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
public User user;
```

**Application class**

```
    User user = new User();

    user.setAddress("asdkapoda");
    user.setName("xaxaxaxa");
    user.setPostCode(3423);

    Credentials credit = new Credentials();
    credit.setPassword("sadsad");
    credit.setUsername("sdadsa");
    session.save(credit);
```

And in database Credential is with user_id = **NULL**.
Hibernate 4.3

Comment: Are you talking about the `user` in the `Credential`? If so, you haven't set the user there to the one you created previously.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is faithfully saving the fact that you, in fact, never associated the `Credentials` object with a `User` object. Try adding `credit.setUser(user);` before the save.

Comment: thats true, You missed `credit.setUser(user);`

You need to add user object to the credit by calling its setter method